# Problem in assign an URL to image tag and show image

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an **img** tag and I want to get an image from an URL and show in it.This URL specifies an *ASPX* page that I get the image from database in it's *FormLoad* and return that image.The problem is that the *FormLoad* method of page doesn't call.
I should say, I get the image from a database using a Link Server.

This code is my URL assigning:

```
imgManager.ImageUrl = "~/Portals/AbsencePresent/Form/SignForm.aspx?ManagerId=" + 
managerObject.Id.ToString();
```

I don't get an error in this line of code and the application runs normally.
I try to copy this URL in browser manually, but nothing happened.

could you help me?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the SignForm.aspx:

```
public partial class SignForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["ManagerId"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = AbsencePresent.BusinessObjects.Helper.GetSign(Request.QueryString["ManagerId"]);
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string signFileName = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                    //string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(signFileName).ToLower();
                    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["SrcFile"];
                    string imageFormat = AbsencePresent.BusinessObjects.Helper.GetContentType(bytes).ToString().ToLower();
                    string contentType = string.Empty;
                    if (imageFormat == "bmp")
                        contentType = "image/bmp";
                    else if (imageFormat == "jpeg")
                        contentType = "image/jpeg";
                    else if (imageFormat == "jpg")
                        contentType = "image/jpeg";
                    else if (imageFormat == "gif")
                        contentType = "image/gif";
                    else if (imageFormat == "png")
                        contentType = "image/png";
                    else if (imageFormat == "tiff")
                        contentType = "image/tiff";

                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.ContentType = contentType;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + signFileName);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the source code of SignForm.aspx.cs

Comment: what is full image path returned by signform?

Comment: I add the SignForm.aspx.cs. In this code, I get the image from database.